# upload from telegram bot

Tags: upload, limit, telegram

I want to upload a file that exists in a telegram server to another server but telegram does not provide a download url link.

I tried to use some bots like pwrtelegrambot or something like that but none of them works.
i tried to write a bot to do this for me but i understand that the bot only can download files up to 20mb and i got this error

> {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: file is too big"}

Is there any way to generate download url from the files that exists in telegram server and upload them to another server like uploadboy or something else??

I will appreciate for any help!!

Answer (score 3):

as it mentioned in this [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq), you can't download files bigger than 20MB.

if you really want to download big files, you should forget about the bots and try to modify telegram clients source codes.([telegram cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) , [android](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram), [webogram](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram))

Answer (score 3):

You can crawl the chat containing your media with a telegram user using [thelethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) ( python client for telegram ), and download the files one by one using the `client.download_media(msg, file_name)` function. `msg` is the telegram message containing the media that you want.

this is a late answer, but just in case anyone faces the same problem ;)